# Python GridInQuestII dynamic library

Tags: python, python-2.7, coordinates, gis, coordinate-systems

I'm trying to convert coordinates from WGS84 to OSGB36 using the method described in the GridInQuestII manual (page 18 or see the picture). In summary it's saying "WindowsError: [Error 193] %1 is not a valid Win32 application". The relevant part of the code is https://ghostbin.com/paste/jum2a, and the traceback link is in the comments (I need higher reputation to post 2 links). I'm using Spyder with Python 2.7, on a 64 bit PC, and I have copied GIQ.dll and GM15GB.dat into the same directory as the py file. Has anyone got any ideas what's wrong, and how I can fix it? Thanks in advance.
[Extract from GridInQuestII manual](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R3Vv6.png)

Comment: Traceback: https://ghostbin.com/paste/8dh3o

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I worked around this by executing the command line batch processing function (giqtrans) via Python using the subprocess.call() function. I had to ensure that the GIQ folder was on the Path (through environment variables), but after that it worked fine. Hopefully this will help anyone else struggling with it.